# Crystal reports - last day of previous month

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I was given this formula in a program, but it's giving me the first of the current month. I need to get the last day of the previous month, so report runs the 3rd day of current month we want only the previous month data.

```
ToNumber(ToText(Year(CurrentDate), 0, "") + ToText(Month(CurrentDate), "00") + '01')
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that our date is number and yyyymmdd. I like this date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)-1 but i cant run the report till a couple of days into the next month so the orders invoice from the last days of prev month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
{datefield} in lastfullmonth
```

or if you just need that last day

```
date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
```

Comment: getdate doesn't seem to be working, Maybe it's a later version of CR?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CDLASTDAYOFMONTH` function along with the usual month/date functions

```
CDLASTDAYOFMONTH(Month(DateAdd ("m", -1, CurrentDate)));
```

Comment: hi this gives error message, 'the remaining text does not appear to be part of formula'

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
maximum(Lastfullmonth)
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer to provide some more detail and explanation as to how/why this solves OP's problem?